# node.js on apache server shows only raw html

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, apache

I've recently been dealing with node.js server atop of apache2. I managed to configure apache virtualhost with the following code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName www.mydomain.com

    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location /gp>
            ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
            ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

It actually displays the raw html backbone (no css or frontend js) if I go to mydomain.com/gp, which is a success already, yet I do not understand why there is no css or any styles whatsoever. Could it be the problem I don't have my node files in /var/www/html but in e.g. ~/user/nodeApp?

Is there anything else I can to to fix this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: From the server, if you open the page localhost:3000 do you see the CSS and JS? (basically, try loading the page directly from the node server instead of going through Apache, which would tell you if it is an Apache issue versus a node issue)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I figured out, that if I put my public folder into /var/www and update paths in index.html then css works normally, yet backend still doesn't work..